# Is Apache hosting better for a WordPress site?

Tags: apache, looking-for-hosting, windows

I have a legacy (early 2000s) Windows IIS hosting package on a company that originally was for a static html site. I have since created a WordPress site on a subdomain of the old one. The problem is because it is a very old hosting package, the wordpress site loads very slowly due to a long TTFB.

I contacted the company to upgrade the package to increase the performance, and they recommended moving from Windows ISS to Linux and Apache because 'Windows hosting and WordPress hate each other' and basically it isn't as optimised for it.

I was just wondering if this was actually true as I did some research and it seems like both Windows and Apache are viable for WordPress sites. It would be great if I don't need to switch so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is unclear and opinion based. "Windows hosting" is ambiguous and is unrelated to "Apache hosting" because you can run Apache on Windows. And your hosting package doesn't tell us anything about the hardware, software, or performance of the system.

Comment: @Rob Oh sorry, I only went by what I wast told by the hosting company. I had a look and believe it runs IIS on windows. The company advised me to, when upgrading the package to a recent one, switch to Apache on Linux for better performance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about compatibility between windows hosting and WordPress as I use neither of them. However from a performance point of view, I would imagine a Linux/Apache server would be better than an old windows server. Especially if the hardware is dated. Thinking about it, it could actually be more compatible as Linux and Apache are open source and free so keeping an Apache server up to date with the latest technologies would be easier and cheaper than an old windows server (probably). Again I have no experience with Windows hosting but as far as personal computers go, Linux is a much faster os and demands less resources from the hardware, which equals better performance.

Comment: There's no compatibility issue. Apache is the web server software and runs perfectly well on Windows. I think the OP is actually referring to IIS. Of more concern would be running a web server on 15+ year old hardware and software, especially when web hosting is hardly the most expensive thing in the world.

Comment: Yes its as @GeoffAtkins says, I had a look and it currently is on IIS on Windows. I was looking to upgrade to a more recent package, but my hosting company advised I also switch to Apache on Linux. I was just wandering if there is actually any benefit of doing the switch.

Comment: @Anon - Usually it's cheaper (both Linux and Apache are open source, depending on the exact choices of software it can be free). Most servers run on them because the performance is good and it's cheaper. But you need to know how to manage a Linux server.

Comment: It depends on your situation. If you have no specific requirements for a windows/(IIS?) server then there should be no issue switching over to a Linux/Apache server and it probably would deliver better performance if only due to the fact that Linux is more lightweight than windows. Personally I stick with Linux/Apache. I wouldn't worry about managing a linux server too much as you'll likely get access to some sort of control panel. Also I'm guessing you do most of your work within wordpress its self? If you need to though, basic Linux operations are easy to learn and youtube has tons of tuts.